# Migrating a page to be an article

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I've decided, that some second level pages I have, should really be blog articles. I want to copy and paste the title and body to an article and then delete the page (is there a better way of doing this?).

Now I'm worrying about already existing links to the pages. I don't want them to break ...

can I somehow enter the old URL as an alias URL for the article? Or maybe forward from
http://mypage.com/level-one/level-two-page/
to
http://mypage.com/2010/07/30/level-two-page-as-article/
without showing the olt level-two-page in the navigation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Vice Versa plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vice-versa/) to change the post type. 
Redirect the URL per .htaccess:

```
Redirect permanent /old-url /new-url
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit in your database "wp_posts" table the row "post_type", simply change "page" to "post". Then set 301 redirect in your .htaccss file. The ID of this page/post remains the same.